# Getting started with an iPad application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios

I have an iPhone application fully finished and it doesn't rely on any specific iPhone functionality that would not be used on an iPad (for example, my iPhone app doesn't use Text Messaging). I use xcode and I use the iPhone simulator to test my app.

How would I go about making an iPad version? Do I need to make a fully new xcode project? I know there is an iPad simulator, but how do I create an iPad version. Also, when I submit to apple, how do I specify the iPhone version and the iPad version.

For instance, in my code I have a UITableView in a particular controller that is size 320x480 (to fit the iPhone). How would I specify an iPad version of that UITableView?

Can anyone explain/give me insight? Thanks!

Comment: Are you interested in a universal application, or two separate applications? Either way, start by control-clicking on the target in Xcode and upgrading for the iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start off creating iPad versions of your existing XIB files.

As far as code, I have something like this setup:

```
#define IDIOM   UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()
#define IPAD     UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
```

and I use it like *something* this:

```
if(IDIOM == IPAD) {
    /* iPad Interface */
    tbleView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768);
} else {
    /* iPhone Interface */
    tbleView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
}
```

Comment: I don't use XIB at all. All my views are programatically made.

Comment: just add those two define's at the top of each of my classes? and then use the if statements throughout?

Comment: I use a Global.h and import that file where I need to use them.

Comment: the iPad resolution is 1024 x 768, however, you will need to compensate depending on your interface layout. If you have a Toolbar at the top, or a tabbar at the bottom, you will need to figure the size of the table depending on those objects, and subtract the height of those.

Comment: well all of my components are made with hard coded location/width/height values.

Comment: Most of those you will need to figure out the size for iPad. If you had used XIB's, you could have used the built-in AutoSizing Mask to recreate iPad version of your interfaces.

Comment: If you are in Portrait mode, the view should be 768 as 1024 would be landscape.

Comment: You should not use hard coded values. iPhone 4 and iPod touch 4th generation use a higher resolution (and iPad 2 might also).

Comment: resolution is different from screen size

Answer (score 2):

In Addition to the UIUserInterfaceIdiom stuff, you may also want to review the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) paying specific attention to the hardware sections.  Also if you haven't seen it [this document](http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/resources/introductiontouniversalapps.pdf) specifically talks about building universal apps.  Unfortunately there's not a perfect one stop shop, but it's not terribly hard, especially if you already have an app and are ready to port.

Hope that helps.